# How can I use multiple iTunes libraries in OS X?

Tags: macos, itunes

Is there a way to have two iTunes libraries?

One would be a larger one that syncs with an iPod; the other would be a subset of that containing the music I listen to more often on my Mac.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pressing the alt-key while launching iTunes opens a library selection dialog.

[image]

Comment: Awesome tip! I didn't know about that! Thanks so much for sharing!

Comment: I think that's what I needed to know. Thanks!

Comment: On Windows the key is Shift, just to note